# How to Match and Extract Values between two files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, gwas

I have two DataFiles, and I need to match and extract the Information

File1

```
Chr,Start,End,ID
6,38517417,38517437,kgp17152035
6,38517556,38517576,rs4254983
6,38517997,38518017,kgp10250023
6,38519465,38519485,kgp17245206
6,38519751,38519771,kgp8446980
```

File2

```
Gene_ID,Gene_Name,RE_Locus
ENSG00000112164.5,GLP1R,chr6:39041458-39041477
ENSG00000112164.5,GLP1R,chr6:39053087-39053106
ENSG00000112164.5,GLP1R,chr6:39049954-39049973
ENSG00000112164.5,GLP1R,chr6:39041701-39041720
ENSG00000112164.5,GLP1R,chr6:39047953-39047972
```

Here I would like to Match the range of the `RE_Locus` Column in File2 with File1 (`Start` & `End` Columns) as range and Whenever it finds a matching range it has to give their `ID`

Desired Output:

```
ID
tsp17152035
rs874983
kgp10250023
rsp17245206
ex8446980
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book1 copy.csv') #file1

df1 = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv') #file2

pd.merge(df, df1, 
         left_on=(df['Start'].astype('str')+'-'+df['End'].astype('str'))
         ,right_on = df1['RE_Locus'].str.slice(start=5 ), how='inner')[['ID']]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Abhishek, small correction in File2. The above code works fine for previous files. Now in file2 like above, I have a range which lies at start & end of file1 this time it has to map and return valid ID

Comment: I am not sure what the change. Is above code not working?

Comment: File1 has 1500 rows and File2 has 161 rows. In fact, I have just given the sample data above. This time I need to check the RE_Locsus range over file1 (Start & End Columns) and extract ID whenever it finds a match

Comment: Hi, I am not really sure if I understood the problem. You output says "sp17152035" which is not available in File1

Comment: Ya What I mean to say is File1 has 1500 rows, so "sp17152035" this id may lie somewhere which matches the particular range

Comment: need python logic how to iterate over 1500 rows and find match range and gives id as output

Comment: you dont need loop, above code will work any number of rows as in this MERGE is getting used, just read each data in respective dataframe

Comment: As mentioned in comment - file1 goes in df & file2 goes in df1